# Why is Rails numericality validator not using normalized value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model has a decimal amount attribute.

```
create_table :foos do |t|
  t.decimal :amount
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I always want the amount to be negative, so I add a normalisation:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :amount, with: -> amount { - amount.abs }
end
```

This seems to work perfectly.

Now, to be safe, I add a validation:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  normalizes :amount, with: -> amount { - amount.abs }
  validates :amount, numericality: {less_than: 0}
end
```

Now when I set the amount to a positive value, although the normalisation converts it to a negative value, the validator seems to think the value is still positive and adds a validation error.

```
foo = Foo.new amount: 4
foo.amount  # => -4
foo.valid?  # => false
foo.errors  # => #<ActiveModel::Error attribute=amount, type=less_than, options={:value=>4, :count=>0}>
```

According to the tests for `normalizes`, [normalisation happens before validation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0add5dba834f2f1b84fcf1bd1b758545b325fb73/activerecord/test/cases/normalized_attribute_test.rb#L35).

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numericality validator seems to be specifically using raw value for validation without taking normalization into account:
*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L129*

```rb
if record.respond_to?(came_from_user)
  if record.public_send(came_from_user)
    raw_value = record.public_send(:"#{attr_name}_before_type_cast")
```

It needs to be this way because strings normalize to numbers (`"foo".to_d # => 0.0`) so validation wouldn't work if it happened after normalization.

You could write your own validation to bypass this problem:

```rb
validate do
  errors.add(:amount, :less_than, value: amount, count: 0) unless amount.negative?
end
```

Comment: I don’t think it’s a bug, but I do think it’s poorly-documented. It looks like it’s intentionally before-save-ish *(as opposed to before-validation-y)*. Not sure I like the approach, but with hooks there, idk ‍♂️

Comment: Well because otherwise the validator wouldn't work because strings normalize to numbers: `"foo".to_d # => 0.0`

Comment: @smathy oh yes, how could i forget

Comment: I updated your otherwise excellent answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: I understood the order in general to be casting (string to number), normalisation (the value passed to `normalizes`'s `with:` proc is already cast), then validation.  I don't see why, in theory at least, the numericality validator couldn't be changed to validate the normalised value.

Comment: @AndyStewart that is the correct order. and yes, you could change it, use `Foo.normalized_attributes` to detect if attribute is normalized and use `amount` instead of `amount_before_type_cast`